# Can I send the value of html like this $("#id").html() to code behind?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, jquery

I have already tried it via ajax but it doesn't work so Help me please !!!!!!
And i tried it into cookie but in code behind didnt see it

Comment: your question not very clear. Are you want to set the attribute id to any tag?

Comment: You should be able to do this via Ajax, could you post the AJAX code that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var datah = $(“#currid”).html()

var data = {
  id: currid,
  html: datah
 };


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "return back" );
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You must encode the html content before transmitting .  You can use `escape` in java script  for this.And you can decode  back it from server

```
 var encodedData= escape($(“#id”).html()) ;
    var postData = { htmlData:encodedData};    
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: postData,
       success: function(msg){
         // do your operation
         }
     });
```

Comment: Your ans has the problem about tag html when it encode by using escape() function the data will longer then 2000 and cant take it to server i have ever try this too thx Mr.null pointer

Comment: @Zrot ,Why you sending html to server  ? Whats your requirement